# _Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with: details="Name resolution failure"

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Versions

-python 2.7.16

-tensorboard: 1.13.1

-tensorflow: 1.13.1

code to reproduce:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
  inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(1))
  inp2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(1)) 
  var = tf.math.multiply(inp,inp2)

sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
with sess.as_default():
  sess = tf_debug.TensorBoardDebugWrapperSession(sess,"grpc://localhost:6064")
  with tf.summary.FileWriter('/home/penalvad/stattus4/stattus4-audio-models/notebooks/',graph=graph,session=sess) as writer:
    tf.summary.initialize(graph=self.graph,session=sess)
    sess.run(var,feed_dict={inp:10.0,inp2:2.0})
```

```py
_Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "Name resolution failure"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1564495830.026710193","description":"Failed to create subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":2721,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1564495830.026708437","description":"Name resolution failure","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3026,"grpc_status":14}]}"
```

So ... iam doing anything wrong or is this a bug ?

update: corrected the code to use the right protocol grpc and the debug port to be 6064, everything seems to be fine now